# Do Periodic & Repeated Jobs keep the same Job ID when repeated? Redis RQ-Scheduler

Tags: python, redis, scheduled-tasks

Let's say I had a job which is scheduled to run every 3 hours.

```
job = scheduler.schedule(
    scheduled_time=datetime.utcnow(),
    func=func,
    interval=10800,
    repeat=None
)

jobID = job.id
```

On the fifth time it runs, will it have the same Job ID as it does on the first time it's added to the scheduler - or does it change?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no it will not. You will in fact notice that even if your job has the same date-time object up to the microsecond level, it still throws a different job ID.

Here's my implementation and experience:

```py
def test():
      print("HELLO")

today=datetime.datetime.today()
today=today.replace(hour=10,minute=15,second=0,microsecond=0)
s1=Scheduler(connection=Redis())


print(today)
s1.schedule(scheduled_time=today,func=test,args=[],interval=10,repeat=None)

jobs1=s1.get_jobs()

for job in jobs1:
      #s1.cancel(job)
      print("first",job,job.id)
```

And here's the output:

```
2022-01-15 10:15:00
first <Job 3a7321d9-8703-4ee4-879c-b0e9f8bdfabe: __main__.test()> 3a7321d9-8703-4ee4-879c-b0e9f8bdfabe
first <Job 59a2cafe-e784-401e-9dcf-deb2da59b20a: __main__.test()> 59a2cafe-e784-401e-9dcf-deb2da59b20a
first <Job eccdf669-1b5d-4a42-aa72-23fa8b09e4bb: __main__.test()> eccdf669-1b5d-4a42-aa72-23fa8b09e4bb
```

Comment: I have tested this exact same code, and I am getting a single line of output.  I was experimenting with periodic jobs and ran into this weirdness as well.  Can't figure out why each execution instance is not getting its own ID.

Comment: I think they want you to grab the job id instantly after creating and never again. @HanSooloo